# problems passing datetime dates between functions in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: datetime, .net-core

I have these functions in a repository in a .NET Core 3.1 class library

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<GridVM>> Get(string proyectoId, DateTime fechaInicio, DateTime fechaFin, bool acumular = false)
{
....
GetDatosParaElGridSinAcumular(ICs, proyectoId, realizadosAcumulados, planificadosAcumulados, realizadosAcumuladosCostes, planificadosAcumuladosCostes, fechaInicio, fechaFin, realizadosEnFecha, planificadosEnFecha, realizadosEnFechaCostes, planificadosEnFechaCostes);
....
}

private List<GridVM> GetDatosParaElGridSinAcumular(List<IC> empleados, string proyectoId, IEnumerable<ValoresAcumulados> realizadoAcumuladoHoras, IEnumerable<ValoresAcumulados> planificadoAcumuladoHoras, IEnumerable<ValoresAcumulados> realizadoAcumuladoCostes, IEnumerable<ValoresAcumulados> planificadoAcumuladoCostes, DateTime fechaInicio, DateTime fechaFin, IEnumerable<ValoresEnFecha> realizadoEnFechaHoras, IEnumerable<ValoresEnFecha> planificadoEnFechaHoras, IEnumerable<ValoresEnFecha> realizadoEnFechaCostes, IEnumerable<ValoresEnFecha> planificadoEnFechaCostes) {
....
}
```

When I execute I see that Get receives these dates fechaInicio = {01/01/2023 0:00:00} and fechaFin = {12/31/2023 0:00:00} but GetDataParaElGridWithoutAccumulate receives these other fechaInicio = {04 /01/0001 0:22:45} fechaFin = {01/01/0001 16:20:06}

I don't know what happened along the way for this translation

I have debugged instruction by instruction and just before the call the dates are not touched at all and immediately after the call to the function that strange thing arrives

If I put a simple function that receives these same parameters without further ado, they are fine for it

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks